# Anchor.click using executeJs function not working in real iPhone safari browser

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, vaadin14

I have a question regarding `executeJs` function.

```
page.executeJs("$0.click();", downloadAnchor.getElement());
```

This line of code is not working in real iPhone Safari browser, though it works in mobile responsive mode from desktop safari. Appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will be "suspicious" of anything starting a download that isn't a *direct* reaction to interaction by the user. This is done as a security precaution since starting to download files without the user's explicit consent can be dangerous in specific cases. Different browsers and configurations have different policies for exactly where to draw the line.

In your case, the download isn't started as a direct consequence of user interaction but instead as direct consequence of receiving a message from the server. This kind of pattern will simply not work reliably no matter what you do.

Instead, you need to design the interaction so that the download is directly triggered by the user. The easiest way of doing that is by having the user directly click on the actual download link. If you want to have some indirection, then you still need to make the action work directly in the browser without going through the server.

Comment: Thanks Leif for the information. I will check redesigning the UI

Comment: My requirement is when a user clicks on a button, it will form a dynamic stream resource (.xlsx file) which will be downloaded. As per current code, an anchor is added and href is set to that with the stream resource, then does the programmatic click so that file is downloaded. How to achieve this without programmatic click and not let user click twice 
 Request your help on this. Thanks